# input validation with getline and (!(cin >> var))

Tags: c++, validation, getline

I'm working on a project for my c++ class, but I'm a little hung up on how to properly validate input to make sure it's correct before proceeding. The following is a function designed to allow user input for a student's name and test scores. My issues involve 'getline' on line 6 and (!(cin >> score[i][j])) on line 11.

For getline, I need a way to check that only alphabetical characters were entered.
For (!(cin >> score...)) If the user enters a integer followed by a character (i.e. "8a") it isn't detected as an input error. Is there any way to remedy this?

EDIT: I've come up with a partial solution thanks to "David Rankin - ReinstateMonica".
I've changed the getline validation to only accept alphabetical characters, spaces, and periods using this bit of code:

```
while (!(names[i].find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. ") == string::npos && !names[i].empty())) // check to make sure there are no invalid characters and names[i] isnt blank
        {
            cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
            getline(cin, names[i]); // Allow for full name entry (first, middle, and last names)
            if (!(names[i].find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. ") == string::npos && !names[i].empty())) // another check, outputs error msg if getline value is invalid
                cout << "Names must consist of letters, periods, or spaces. \n";
        }
```

However I'm still stumped on how to validate the (!(cin >> score[i][j])) portion. Would it be possible to create a temporary char array for score[i][j] and then test if each element of the char array is a number? Or is there some easier method?

```
void getNameScore(string names[], double score[NGS_SIZE][S_SIZE], char grade[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NGS_SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
        getline(cin, names[i]); // Allow for full name entry (first, middle, and last names)
        double total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < S_SIZE; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter " << names[i] << "'s test " << j + 1 << " score: ";
            while (!(cin >> score[i][j]) || score[i][j] < 0 || score[i][j] > 100) // input validation 0 to 100 as well as cin data type error checking
            {
                cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100: ";
                cin.clear(); // clear error flags when a non-integer value is entered in line 38
                cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // clear input buffer
            }
            total += score[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // clear getline buffer on line 32
        double avg = total / S_SIZE;
        if (avg >= 90)
            grade[i] = 'A';
        else if (avg >= 80)
            grade[i] = 'B';
        else if (avg >= 70)
            grade[i] = 'C';
        else if (avg >= 60)
            grade[i] = 'D';
        else
            grade[i] = 'F';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are learning the finer details of input handling. `"8a"` will be taken as the `double 8` followed by `'a'` which is left unread in your input stream. There is no error because there was a successful conversion to `double`. To check if characters remain, you can use [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::peek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek). To check if `name` is all alpha-characters, you can use [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) (or `find_first_not_of`)

Comment: Users are the worst sort of scum. When they aren't deliberately trying to break your code to get at the goodies on the other side, they are deliberately trying to break your code just for fun. And those few who aren't never seem to be able to hit the right keys and drop typos <expletive deleted>ing everywhere. Don't trust them to do anything right.

Comment: if entering "8a" sets 'double var' to 8, doesn't that leave 'a' in the buffer? If so, is there a way I can check the cin buffer to make sure it is empty? and if it's not empty, force the while loop to continue until a valid input is made?